# C# Windows Forms Application show/hide toolstrips using next/previous buttons

Tags: c#, controls

I'm not sure if this is possible or not since I'm new to C# and Windows Forms Applications. I currently have a single form. Inside the form I have `flowLayoutPanel`.

Inside this panel I have `toolStripMain`, `toolStrip0 [TabIndex 0]`, `toolStrip1 [TabIndex 1]` and `toolStrip2 [TabIndex2]`. The `toolStripMain` is always visible and I have a previous button and next button on this one.

When form loads, `toolStrip0` is visible and the other 2 are set to Hide(). For each click on "next" I want to hide current toolstrip whether it be 0,1 or 2 and show the next toolstrip and once it reaches the last toolstrip it resets and starts at 0.

In other words, for each click of "next" button I need current toolstrip to hide and show next strip in order. The following code is only for 1 click.

```
private void forward_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStrip0.Hide();
        toolStrip1.Show();
    }
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add a variable to your form class named CurrentStep.  Now it is simple to decide which strip should be visible and whether or not the Next/Prev buttons should be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of blinding to a certain forward/backward buttons, why not blind to the `toolstrip` itself. It looks like the correct method to bind too would be the `Toolstrip.ItemClicked` event.

Based off the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.itemclicked(v=vs.110).aspx)

> An event handler reports on the **occurrence** of the ItemClicked event.

So the event will fire for the current toolstrip item clicked.

```
public ToolStrip prevToolStripClicked = null;
...
...

private void ToolStrip1_ItemClicked(Object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e) 
{
    if(prevToolStripClicked != null)
    {
        prevToolStripClicked.hide();
    }
    prevToolStripClicked = e.ClickedItem;
    e.ClickedItem.show(); // prevToolStripClicked.show();
}
```

Keep track of the previous `Toolstrip` and check on the `ItemClicked` event if it's not null, meaning nothing has been clicked, then `.hide()` the previous button and then set the previous button to the current and `.show()` it.

This might work, but I'm not that familiar with C#. This seems to be a sensible approach.